# Inserting double dictionary into MYSQL with PYTHON

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, dictionary

I cant figure any way to do this. I have this dictionary from an API request and I am trying to store it into a database.
This is the dictionary

```
    descr = {
                        "id": "order-1",
                        "location": {
                        "latitude": location.latitude,
                        "longitude": location.longitude

                    },
                    "serviceDuration": 400,
                    "quantity": 2
                }
```

then i tried to set each item i need to a variable (which doesnt set some reason but print(descr["id"]) would print)

```
    id_api = str(descr["id"])
    location_latitude = str(descr["location"]["latitiude"])
    location_longitude = str(descr["location"]["longitude"])
    serviceDuration = str(descr["serviceDuration"])
    quantity = str(descr["quantity"])
```

then im trying to insert into database which works for me with regular variables but doesnt work with this dictionary or how im doing now, because of above issue with setting variable to dictionary item

```
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="",
        database="thedb"
        )

    sql = "INSERT INTO customers (chatid, id_api,location_latitude,location_longitude,serviceDuration,quantity) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"

    val = (str(chat_id),str(id_api),str(location_latitude),str(location_longitude),str(serviceDuration),str(quantity))
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)

    mydb.commit()
```

Comment: when you say "doesn't work" what *exactly* is the actual result?

Comment: @DanielFarrell like i set    id_api = str(descr["id"])     then print(id_api) wont print anything just stops

Comment: Why do you convert so many times to str?? If you do _id_api = str(descr["id"])_ then id_api is a string, you don´t need to convert it again in str(id_api). And you shouldn´t store all your values in your DB as strings, there are a lot more usefull data types in mysql

Comment: @nacho ignore the extra str() I tried to store as list as well but that doesnt work. Mysql does not like the curly brackets {}

Comment: if anyone wondering, @nacho right use proper types